# Spring TransactionManagement with Atomikos

Tags: spring, spring-boot, datasource, spring-transactions, atomikos

I am trying to boot up a spring application with Atomikos maven dependency

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jta-atomikos</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Am also autowiring as following

```
 @Autowired
    JtaTransactionManager jtaTransactionManager;
```

application.yaml file is as follows

```
spring:
  mvc:
    throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
    resources:
      add-mappings: false
  jta:
    atomikos:
      connectionfactory:
        ignore-session-transacted-flag: false
        unique-resource-name: xa.amq
        min-pool-size: 10
        max-pool-size: 20
      datasource:
        unique-resource-name: xa.db
        min-pool-size: 10
        max-pool-size: 20
        test-query: "select 1"
      properties:
        default-jta-timeout: 50000
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://mydatabasehost:3306/test
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: test
    password: test
    initialization-mode: always
```

It starts fine with above yaml configurations.

However, for my use case, I want my transaction manager to skip using the default spring datasource and instead I want to dynamically register datasource beans after the start up. I wanted to know if that is possible.  If I remove my datasource settings from above yaml file, I get following error

```
15:15:19.322 [main] WARN  com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosXAConnectionFactory - XAConnectionFactory: failed to create pooled connection - DBMS down or unreachable?
java.sql.SQLException: Database not available
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.BasicEmbeddedDataSource40.setupResourceAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedXADataSource.getXAConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosXAConnectionFactory.createPooledConnection(AtomikosXAConnectionFactory.java:28)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.createPooledConnection(ConnectionPool.java:98)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.addConnectionsIfMinPoolSizeNotReached(ConnectionPool.java:86)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:60)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:49)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.pool.ConnectionPoolWithConcurrentValidation.<init>(ConnectionPoolWithConcurrentValidation.java:23)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.init(AbstractDataSourceBean.java:294)
    at org.springframework.boot.jta.atomikos.AtomikosDataSourceBean.afterPropertiesSet(AtomikosDataSourceBean.java:49)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1837)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1774)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:307)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1171)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an Atomikos limitation because it allows dynamic addition of datasources.

It looks like Spring Boot's convention-over-configuration trying to create a default datasource if you have none. I am not a Spring Boot expert so I am not sure if this can be suppressed. However, there is probably no harm in using a dummy default datasource in your configuration if that help.

Best regards